# javascript - merging arrays with like elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have a 2 dimensional array like this:

```
[[1,4], [1,3], [2,4], [6,4], [2,5]]
```

I want to merge the inner arrays so that those that share the same first element will be come one array by summing their second elements. So the output for this example would be:

```
[[1,7], [2,9], [6,4]]
```

What would be the best way to do this in javascript? I can use underscore.js

Comment: Iterate over the array and keep track of the "keys" you have already seen. If you have seen the "key", add the current value to its value, if not, remember the key and value. Do you want to preserve the original order?

Comment: preserving the order doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using temporary object:

```js
var a = [[1,4], [1,3], [2,4], [6,4], [2,5]]

var o = {};

a.forEach(function(e) {
    if (o[e[0]]) {
        o[e[0]] += e[1];
    } else {
        o[e[0]] = e[1];
    }
});

var res = Object.keys(o).map(function(k){
    return [+k, o[k]];
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6, you can use a map:

```
var arr = [[1,4], [1,3], [2,4], [6,4], [2,5]],
    map = new Map();
for(let [key,val] of arr)
  map.set(key, (map.get(key) || 0) + val);
[...map]; // [[1,7], [2,9], [6,4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "reduce" the array to an object with the first values being properties and second values aggregated as, well, values, than turn this object back to an array:

```
var obj = arr.reduce(function(r, curr){
  r[curr[0]] = (r[curr[0]] || 0) + curr[1];
  return r;
}, {});

var newArr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
  return[k, obj[k]];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `Array.forEach` method and custom `keyMap` object:

```
var arr = [[1,4], [1,3], [2,4], [6,4], [2,5]], keyMap = {}, result = [];

arr.forEach(function(v){
    var prop = 'key' + v[0];
    (!(prop in keyMap))? keyMap[prop] = v[1] : keyMap[prop] += v[1];
});

for (var k in keyMap) {
    result.push([parseInt(k[3]), keyMap[k]]);
}

console.log(result); // [[1,7], [2,9], [6,4]]
```